# Getting route values in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Using MVC 3, a user gets to a URL like `app/Controller/Details/123`

An `$.ajax` request on the page posts back to `/Controller/AnotherAction`.

Inside `AnotherAction`, I want to get the `IDNumber` seen in the browser...

I've tried looking at the `Request` object but they all `return Controller/AnotherAction`:

```
HttpContext.Request.Path, 
HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsolutePath,
HttpContext.Request.RawUrl,
HttpContext.Request.Url.ToString()
```

Is there any way to get the ID number from Details that the browser is seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are checking it in the action method which is being invoked by your ajax call, All those `Request` Properties will give you the information about your current Ajax request. Not the one you have in your address bar.

You need to exclusively pass the relevant IDs / key as parameters of the action method and use those.

Comment: I was afraid of that... Thanks. Do you know of a fileupload plugin that lets me also pass additional data like IDs?

Comment: I found this.  http://elegantcode.com/2010/08/27/file-uploads-and-mvc-controllers/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly then all you need to do is add a parameter to you Action Method with the name id.  It can be either a string or int type.  Model Binding will handle the translation.  This assumes that you are passing the id up to the server in your AJAX call.

If that doesn't work please add the signature of your method to your question. Also show us your ajax code.

Comment: I'm using a fileupload plugin that doesn't let me pass other data... Do you know of a fileupload plugin that lets me also pass additional data like IDs?